# What commands can be issued to Excel for Mac from the terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, ms-office

I know I can tell Excel to open a file with:

`open MAC\ Addresses.xlsx -a "Microsoft Excel.app/"`

But I cannot figure out how to do anything with Excel from the terminal.

Where can I find a list of the commands that can be sent to Excel from the terminal?

Comment: did you try `/Applications/Microsoft\ Excel.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Excel --help` ?

Comment: Had not, but when I just did it opened a blank workbook. And I got this repeating in terminal: 'Microsoft Excel[98574:4719817] Stream 0x7fcee5f60e30 is sending an event before being opened' and terminal is stuck (no prompt)

Comment: There currently seem at least three questions in your post: How can I catch the output of `arp -a` in a form useable by Excel, how can I launch Excel from Terminal with this and how can I send commands from Terminal to Excel.  So can you edit your question to focus on the main objective here?

Comment: The sending commands from the terminal would be done with osascript.  Excel's applescript dictionary isn't *extensive*, but it works.  Your command 'arp -a | > newcsv.csv' would indeed create an empty file, as your syntax is incorrect.  You don't pipe into a redirection operator.  And I don't think you're going to get a reasonable CSV file without some pre-processing, probably through awk or sed.

Comment: Have rearranged the question to clearly identify my question. --- And i see now that i will need to take the arp output into a txt file and then replace spaces with commas before handing that off to excel. I'm a novice, obviously, and am learning as I go.

Comment: While scripting Excel sounds... interesting, you've got the wrong solution.  You want XLS files, that doesn't have to involve scripting the behemoth that is Excel.  I think if I were going to do it script-ly, I'd use Numbers rather than Excel.  But all you want to do is write XLS files.  Python +XlsxWriter, maybe.

Comment: I would actually like to use excel to convert files from the old **xls** format to **xlsx**, but not the strict open format. Right now, I have to do them all by hand. I tried using LibreOffice but that converts to the strict open format which isn't what I need. I wouldn't like to script excel either but it's possibly "my only viable option" at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is primarily a GUI application, there isn't much more you can do from the Terminal than using `open` to have it opening a file.

Excel has a little AppleScript interface you can use via `osascript`, but it only supports a minimal set of commands.